# svn: Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to PROPFIND

Tags: apache, svn

We need to work with some SVN repository via proxy.

> Direct url: http://host.com.ua/app
>   URL via proxy: http://proxy.com.ua/svn/app

We added following lines to Apache:

```
ProxyPass        /svn/app http://host.com.ua/app
ProxyPassReverse /svn/app http://host.com.ua/app
```

Now I can access http://host.com.ua/app via browser.
I can checkout working copy using direct URL http://host.com.ua/app.

But I can't access repository via our proxy using svn command line tool or TortoiseSVN.
**There is following error:**

> svn co http://proxy.com.ua/svn/app/trunk/workshop/dev
>   svn: Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to PROPFIND request for '/app/!svn/vcc/default'

What does this error mean and hot to fix it?

**UPDATE:**
As I can see only following configuration works:

```
ProxyPass        /app http://host.com.ua/app
ProxyPassReverse /app http://host.com.ua/app
```

But it is not suitable for us.
We need have word "svn" in URL.

Comment: PROPFIND method seems to be disabled somewhere else in Apache's config